# Selecting the appropriate sensor?

Tags: sensor, adc, resolution

I use an analog input (AI) reading board with 12 bit resolution and read range +-10V. The board AI reading error is given as +-5mV.

I need select a pressure sensor, one of them gives 0-5V output, the other gives 0-10V, so which is ideal for my board.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is choose the sensor which has the widest output swing which doesn't go beyind the input range of your analog input.

The 0-10v sensor has double the range of the 0-5v sensor, and doesn't go beyond the input range of ±10v. Therefore you should choose the 0-10v sensor.

Since that sensor covers half of the analog input range, you will use 11 of the 12 bits of resolution.

Comment: Note that you *could* use an op-amp, powered from +/-15v, to scale the sensor output to the +/-10v range, giving you most of that bit back. It will introduce a little bit of error and noise, but should give you at least half of that bit resolution.

Comment: Mr rocketmagnet thanks for response. What if ai board voltage range can be tunable, can be set 0-5 v or 0-10. Still 0-10v output sensor good for me?

Comment: If you can set the input voltage range to 0-10v, then definitely do that, and use the 0-10v sensor.